# Inconsistency in Clojure: functions in macros and IllegalArgumentException

Tags: clojure

Two following examples of using a function in a macro result in evaluations without errors.

```
(defmacro works []
  (let [f (fn [] 1)]
    `(~f)))
(works)
;; => 1

(defn my-nullary-fn []
  (fn [] 2))
(defmacro also-works []
  (let [f (my-nullary-fn)]
    `(~f)))
(also-works)
;; => 2
```

However,

```
(defmacro does-not-work []
  (let [f (constantly 3)]
    `(~f)))
(does-not-work)
```

throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found
for class clojure.core$constantly$fn__4051
```

Likewise,

```
(defn my-unary-fn [x]
  (fn [] x))
(defmacro also-does-not-work []
  (let [f (my-unary-fn 4)]
    `(~f)))
(also-does-not-work)
```

throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found
for class user$my_other_fn$fn__12802
```

What might be the reason? Is there a difference between function objects returned by `fn`, `my-nullary-fn`, `constantly` and `my-unary-fn`?

I'm running Clojure 1.5.1.

[CLJ-946](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-946) might be related.

Comment: Why do you need to insert a compiled function object into the parse tree? Why not just "(let [f '(constantly 3)'] ... )"?

Comment: @RafałDowgird I don't need to. What you suggest would surely work. My goal however is to determine what is the difference between examples I demonstrated and how are they evaluated under the hood. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [`clojure.lang.Compiler.ObjExpr#emitValue()`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/0b73494c3c855e54b1da591eeb687f24f608f346/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L4404). Any instance objects which appear directly in code (or generated code, in the case of macro-expansion results) must either:

- Be of a type compiler knows how to instantiate or emit a reference to; or
- Have `print-dup` defined for their type, in which case the compiler emits object instantiation via round-tripping through the reader.

Function objects do have a `print-dup` implementation, but it constructs read-eval forms which only call the 0-argument version of the function class constructor:

```
(print-dup (fn [] 1) *out*)
;; #=(user$eval24491$fn__24492. )
(let [x 1] (print-dup (fn [] x) *out*))
;; #=(user$eval24497$fn__24498. )
```

Clojure closures are implemented via function-classes which accept their closed-over variable values as constructor arguments.  Hence:

```
(let [f (fn [] 1)] (eval `(~f)))
;; 1
(let [x 1, f (fn [] x)] (eval `(~f)))
;; IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found ...
```

So now you know, and know why to avoid directly inserting function objects into generated code, even when it "works."

Answer (score 1):

See this example that does also throw the exception:

```
(defmacro does-also-not-work []
  (let [x 4
        f (fn [] x)]
    `(~f)))
```

Just like the result of `constantly`, but unlike your first two examples, `f` here is a closure. Apparently, closures created during macro-expansion time do not persist.