# How can you make a record forward a protocol?

Tags: clojure, delegates, polymorphism, protocols, record

I want to attach a different protocol to each instance of a record. What's a clean, non-repetitious way to do that in Clojure?

Specifically, I've got a protocol something like this:

```
(defprotocol LinkPolicy
  (lp-boost [dock g to])
  (lp-reduce-to-uncommitted [dock g to])
  (lp-reciprocate-commitment [dock g from])
  (lp-reciprocate-no-commitment [dock g from])
  (lp-normalize-after-add [dock g to weight])
  (lp-committed? [dock g to])
  . . .) ; more methods than this, even
```

And I want to define a record something like this:

```
(defrecord Dock [nodeid name link-policy]
  LinkPolicy
  (forward all methods to link-policy))
```

I suppose I could implement forwarding something like this:

```
(defrecord Dock [nodeid name link-policy]
  LinkPolicy
  (lp-boost [dock g to]
    (lp-boost link-policy dock g to))
  (lp-reduce-to-uncommitted [dock g from]
    (lp-reduce-to-uncommitted link-policy dock g from))
  (lp-reciprocate-commitment [dock g from]
    (lp-reciprocate-commitment link-policy dock g from))
  ; lots more forwarding methods here . . .
  . . .)))
```

but that seems somewhat less elegant than what I've come to expect is possible in Clojure. Also, every time I redefine LinkPolicy, I'm going to have to modify Dock, too. (And aren't there name-clashes between the methods inside Dock and the `link-policy` methods?)

What's a better way?

Comment: So by 'each instance of a record" you mean you have multiple different types of records each extending your `LinkPolicy` protocol?

Comment: It looks as a strange design decision as you would like to dispatch on the `link-policy` type and not on your record type. Could you change the design to take that difference into account? It would be good to know what kind of problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl I only have one record type, `Dock`, and I want to be able to give each instance a different `LinkPolicy`, indicated in the `link-policy` field. The overall problem involves building a variety of [port graphs](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4098v1.pdf) (it's research for a Ph.D.). I'm definitely open to considering another approach to the design. I only started Clojure a week ago, and I may well be going against the grain of the language. And actually, even my proposed-and-rejected implementation above is not compiling.

Comment: Why does the caller need to treat a `Dock` as a `LinkPolicy`? In other words, if I have a `Dock` called `dock`, why is it necessary that I be able to call `(lp-boost dock)` instead of `(lp-boost (:link-policy dock))`?

Comment: @Elogent Interesting idea. I'm probably just conceptually confused about protocols and records. That may be the dose of sanity I needed. Come to think of it, what you suggest is exactly how my Scala version did it. Anyway, in Clojure, my code that actually invokes `LinkPolicy` methods is written generically: "I don't care what you pass me, as long as it supports `LinkPolicy`." This has enabled me to do handy things like `(extend clojure.lang.Keyword LinkPolicy my-map-of-methods)`. It seems natural, when constructing a `Dock` record, to attach a `LinkPolicy` to it. Now reconsidering…

Comment: @Elogent OK, here's why: What's happening is that things _with_ LinkPolicies get linked. IOW, each node in the graph "has" a LinkPolicy, which tells how to link it validly. It's strange to think of linking LinkPolicies themselves. So, I wouldn't want to say "boost this Dock's LinkPolicy to that Dock's LinkPolicy", as suggested by `(lp-boost (:link-policy this-dock) graph (:link-policy that-dock))`. I want to say "boost this Dock to that Dock, according to this Dock's LinkPolicy." The only thing that's unusual is that I want different Dock instances to have different LinkPolicies.

Comment: I just found a function called [`specify`](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/specify+i.e.+reify+for+instances), which can attach a protocol to a record instance, but apparently it's only available in ClojureScript.

Comment: @BenKovitz You could create a `LinkPolicyContainer` protocol that defines a `link-policy` method, akin to Clojure's [`Seqable`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Seqable.java) interface. Then, for any record that implements `LinkPolicyContainer`, call `link-policy` on that record, then call one of the `LinkPolicy` methods on the returned value, passing in the two things you want to link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really need it (which i really doubt about), there is a way:

let's say we have a protocol `StuffDoer`:

```
(defprotocol StuffDoer
  (do-important-stuff [this x])
  (do-other-important-stuff [this x y]))
```

In fact this protocol is just a map defining protocol's behaviour:

```
user> StuffDoer
{:on user.StuffDoer, :on-interface user.StuffDoer, 
 :sigs {:do-important-stuff {:name do-important-stuff, :arglists ([this x]), :doc nil}, :do-other-important-stuff {:name do-other-important-stuff, :arglists ([this x y]), :doc nil}}, 
 :var #'user/StuffDoer, :method-map {:do-important-stuff :do-important-stuff, :do-other-important-stuff :do-other-important-stuff}, 
 :method-builders {#'user/do-other-important-stuff #function[user/eval20549/fn--20550], 
                   #'user/do-important-stuff #function[user/eval20549/fn--20565]}}
```

so we have all the methods' definitions, to use them inside `extend`.
Let's make this custom `extend` function:

```
(defn extend-forwarding [t p fwd-to]
  (extend
      t p
      (into {} (map (fn [[method-var _]]
                      [(keyword (.sym method-var))
                       (fn [this & args]
                         (apply method-var (fwd-to this) args))])
                    (:method-builders p)))))
```

it dynamically builds a map for `extend`, getting all the methods of protocol and generating proxy function for every method.

let's test it:

```
(defrecord ConcreteDoer [v]
  StuffDoer
  (do-important-stuff [this x]
    (println "doing stuff:" v x))
  (do-other-important-stuff [this x y]
    (println "doing other stuff:" v x y)))

(defrecord ConcreteDoerWithForwarding [fwd-inst])
```

in repl:

```
user> (extend-forwarding ConcreteDoerWithForwarding StuffDoer :fwd-inst)
nil

user> (do-important-stuff
       (ConcreteDoerWithForwarding. (ConcreteDoer. :aaa))
       10)
doing stuff: :aaa 10
nil

user> (do-other-important-stuff
       (ConcreteDoerWithForwarding. (ConcreteDoer. :aaa))
       10 20)
doing other stuff: :aaa 10 20
nil
```

Comment: Wow, this looks like the truly general and straightforward approach. If I'd checked Stack Overflow a few hours ago, I probably would have done it this way. I came up with another approach, posted in another answer, but if I ever need to do forwarding again, or I need to add more flexibility, I'll definitely take this approach. It had not even occurred to me that you can just read the methods straight out of the protocol and pass them to `extend`. Such simplicity!

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

By accident I have found a macro that allows to define a protocol with delegating all method calls to another object in [`useful`](https://github.com/amalloy/useful) library: [`delegating-defrecord`](https://github.com/amalloy/useful/blob/7d32d01c6edc56740f3d933c36a15e3cd61ebb94/src/flatland/useful/experimental/delegate.clj#L89). It's under experimental namespace, but you might find it... useful :).

---

This is not a direct answer for your answer, but I thought I would share some ideas how you could approach your problem.

I am not sure how your implementations of LinkPolicy protocol look like but from the included snippet it seems the protocol contains a lot of methods. That might be a sign of violating the Interface Segregation Principle from SOLID. Also I don't know if/how your implementations are different one from another - do you have some implementations having exactly the same implementations for some of the protocol methods?

If that is the case, I would consider using multimethods. That would give you the flexibility to have a separate dispatch logic for each of the methods and have various objects to be dispatched to the same implementation.

You could instead define a separate multimethod for each protocol method:

```
(defmulti lp-boost
  ;; dispatch function
  (fn [g to]
    (cond
      (some-cond-1 ...) :dispatch-value-1))

(defmulti lp-reduce-to-uncommitted
  (fn [g to] ...))

;; and so on for remaining functions
```

Your dispatch function could return a simple keyword or even a vector or keywords so you could dispatch for example using a type of the object and some other properties (e.g. for `Dock` you could have `[:dock :lp-boost-impl-1]` or `[:dock :lp-boost-impl-2]` etc.)

Then you could define your implementations for your dispatch values:

```
(defmethod lp-boost :dispatch-value-1
  [g to]
  ...)
```

Using multimethods won't have some of the nice properties protocol give you (all the behaviour is grouped, if a type implements a protocol then all the methods will be defined for it, better dispatch performance etc.) but you would gain a lot of flexibility in how you choose implementation of methods.

Comment: Thanks. I had been shying away from learning about multimethods, partly because they're said to be slow, but this problem is probably a good fit, and now I see how they'd apply. Indeed most of my linking protocols share a lot of methods. I "mix" them with the `merge` function (illustrated in the unit test in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36684879/1393162) I just posted). I don't _think_ the polymorphic design violates the Interface Segregation Principle, but now I'm thinking about it…

Comment: I have found a library with `delegating-defrecord` you might want to try. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Automatically define record types, one per protocol

The trick is to programmatically define a separate record type corresponding to each distinct protocol. That is, the program defines a new record each time it comes up with a distinct method-map that you want to "stick" on your original record type. Obviously, this only works if the number of distinct protocols is small enough that you don't swamp memory with these different artificial record types. Also, you couldn't use this trick to assign different link protocols to different keywords (see below).

The following function defines a record type for a given "dockclass", which is a map containing both a name and a method-map for the link protocol. It returns the constructor.

```
(def ^:dynamic link-policy-for-eval)

(defn make-dock-maker [dockclass]
  (binding [link-policy-for-eval (:link-policy dockclass)]
    (let [dockclass-name (name (:name dockclass))
          record-sym (symbol (str "Dock-" dockclass-name))
          ctor-sym (symbol (str "->Dock-" dockclass-name))]
      (eval `(defrecord ~record-sym ~'[nodeid dock-name]))
      (eval `(extend ~record-sym
                     ~'fargish.links/LinkPolicy
                     link-policy-for-eval))
      ctor-sym))))
```

For example, if you have a dockclass named `:input`, `make-dock-maker` will define a record called `Dock-input` and return its constructor `->Dock-input`.

I store that constructor in a place where it can be retrieved by a function called `dock`, which calls it to construct a new dock:

```
(defn dock [node dock-name]
  (let [maker (get-in node [:dock dock-name :dockclass :maker])]
    (maker (:nodeid node) dock-name)))
```

So, there is a single function to call to make whatever dock is appropriate to the node, with the appropriate linking protocol. Nowhere in the code do you need to refer to any of the generated record types or constructors by name.

There is one main non-obvious thing to note, which cost me a lot of effort to figure out:

- Generated code, as in an eval or a macro, [cannot contain function objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452554/1393162). The var `link-policy-for-eval` provides a place to hold the method-map (whose values are all functions) where eval can see it.

### Why forwarding by polymorphism is so good

When the objects being linked satisfy LinkPolicy, rather than providing a way to get a LinkPolicy, the calling code is wonderfully simple. For example, here's some code that makes use of automatic dispatching on docks with different link protocols:

```
(defn make-reciprocal-edits-for [g {:keys [from to]}]
  (if (lp-committed? from g to)
      (lp-reciprocate-commitment to g from)
      (lp-reciprocate-no-commitment to g from))))
```

The code doesn't become *enormously* complicated if I have to extract a link policy from every dock before doing anything with it, but it definitely adds some clutter everywhere and obscures the main ideas.

To write a simple unit test, I wanted to use keywords for docks instead of constructing records that refer to all the stuff needed when the whole program is running. `extend` made that easy:

```
(deftest test-exclusive-linking
  (extend clojure.lang.Keyword LinkPolicy (merge vanilla exclusive-linking))
  (->/do (uber/digraph :a :b :c)
    (do-action (Boost. :a :b))
    (->is (= <> (uber/digraph :c [:a :b 1.0])))
    (do-action (Boost. :a :c))
    (->is (= <> (uber/digraph :b [:a :c 1.0])))))
```

That only works as long as it's OK for every keyword to have the same link policy. If you wanted to give different link policies to different keywords, then you'd have to use a more general approach like what is shown in the other answers.